# OpenGl and OpenCV in Xcode

Tags: xcode, opengl, opencv

I'm doing my thesis for my undergrad degree. I'm trying to emulate the psmove, but just using computer vision instead of the combination of object tracking and hardware that Sony uses in the controller.

I have done the project in Xcode as a command line tool. This is so that I can easily use the same code in VS. I'm using openCV. In order to demonstrate the controller, I need to write some kind of short game/demo. I plan to do this in openGL.

However, the architecture settings for openGL and openCV in xcode are different, and I can't get the two to compile together. I was wondering if anyone knew a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you build OpenCV from source (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port) you can build it for the architecture you got OpenGL working with.